# Using NMF for generating recommendations

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-algebra, recommendation-engine

While using non-negative matrix factorization for generating recommendations, how do I reconstruct data for a new user?

I am following this equation `data.dot(H.T.dot(np.linalg.pinv(H.dot(H.T))).dot(H))` for reconstruction where `H` represents the latent components and `data` consists of the new data containing missing entries.

But seem to be going wrong somewhere, since I do not get the expected results (those from other methods such as sklearn NMF, specifically the `inverse_transform` method).

Comment: [Two people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340540/reconstructing-new-data-using-sklearn-nmf-components-vs-inverse-transform-does-n) working on the same task at the same university at the same time? Maybe you should speak to each other :-). Anyways: you both misinterpret what ```inverse_transform``` does, as described in the link above.

Comment: Thanks, will check with the aforementioned. However, I still do not seem to understand what I missed in inverse_transform.. Do you mind elaborating a bit?

Answer (score 3):

see https://cambridgespark.com/content/tutorials/implementing-your-own-recommender-systems-in-Python/index.html

For pyothn scikit-learn, you can use:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html

```
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF
model = NMF(n_components=2, init='random', random_state=0)
W = model.fit_transform(data)
H = model.components_
```

Where `data` is the matrix you want to decomose. `W` and `H` is the nonnegative factor

you can predict the new recommend or called completed the `data` matrix by `WH'`

Comment: first link is broken